# jquery animate to a certain position

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have a 3 column `<table>` or `<div>` with widths of `50%` `200px` and `empty`

I  want to use jQuery to animate a off screen element into view with it's ending location being relative to the left edge of the 2nd column.

So say I am viewing page on a large screen and the edge of the second column is `900px` from the left side of the window. I want the animation to stop `100px` from the edge of the 2nd column so at `800px` from the left

However the page might be viewed on a smaller screen. So the stopping location might end up being... `400px` from the left.

How do I get the location of the side of a element and then apply it to my animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `offset()`.

```
var left = $(".middlecolumn").offset().left + $(".middlecolumn").width() - 100;
$(".animatedblock").animate({ left: left });
```

Comment: Thanks although -100 seemed to make it animate to the same location as the .element so i adjusted that...